# How do I get values from 2d QUEUE

Tags: c++, queue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    queue<int, int> q1;
    q1.push({3, 5});
    int x = q1.front().first;
    int y = q2.front().second;
    cout << x, y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know where cause the error, can you please point out for me?

Comment: Show your code. No idea what `queue` is. [example]

Comment: where did you define q2? Why you use q2.front(), not q1?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to store `std::pair<int, int>` in a `std::queue`, the following does this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::queue<std::pair<int, int>> q1;  // <-- Note the declaration here
    q1.push({3, 5});
    int x = q1.front().first;
    int y = q1.front().second;
    std::cout << x << " "  << y;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 5
```